# Как расширить класс?

Tags: c++, ооп

Предположим, у меня есть класс для работы с XML, и я хочу добавить в него метод, но чтобы класс об этом не знал. Простое наследование не подходит.Если использовать простое наследование, то скажем функция `SimpleXmlNode CreateChild(const std::string& name);` будет возвращать объект, у которого нет нового метода `each` и он будет недоступен в скрипте.  На ум приходит слово *миксины*, но я что-то не соображу. Если делать на шаблонах, то придется всё засовывать в заголовочные файлы, а я очень хотел бы этого избежать.

```
class SimpleXmlNode
{
    public:
        explicit SimpleXmlNode();
        SimpleXmlNode(const SimpleXmlNode& node);
        virtual ~SimpleXmlNode();

        const std::string Attribute(const std::string& name) const;
        SimpleXmlNode operator[](const std::string& name);
        int AttributeInt(const std::string& name) const;

        // Write
        SimpleXmlNode CreateChild(const std::string& name);
}
```

я хочу добавить функцию `each`:

```
SimpleXmlNode& each(Sqrat::Function callback) {
        int i = 0;
        for (auto& node: childs) {
            Sqrat::SharedPtr<bool> res = callback.Evaluate<bool>(i, node);

            if (!!res && *res) {
                break;
            }
            i++;
        }
        return *this;
    }
```

Чтобы вы понимали, `Sqrat::Function callback` - это коллбэк-функция, написанная на скриптовом языке.

мне нужно функцию each вызывать из скрипта:

```
node.each(function(index,elem){ /*do something*/});
```

А сам класс регистрируется в скриптовой виртуальной машине:

```
 vm.GetRootTable().Bind("SimpleXmlNode", Class<SimpleXmlNode>(vm.GetVM(), "SimpleXmlNode").
        Func("Attribute", &SimpleXmlNode::Attribute).
        Func("AttributeInt", &SimpleXmlNode::AttributeInt).
...
        Func("GetAttributeCount", &SimpleXmlNode::GetAttributeCount)
        Func("each", &SimpleXmlNode::each)
    );
```

Но я не хочу, чтобы класс `SimpleXmlNode` знал что-либо об этих скриптах и зависел от лишних модулей.

Comment: в с++ нет методов:) поэтому вопрос малось некорректен:))) В с++ есть функции классов.

можно зайти с другой стороны.  Функции классов отличаются от обычных функций тем, что у них есть неявный первый аргумент, который указывает на объект, который его вызвал. То есть, можно создать свою функцию, которая будет первым аргументом получать указатель на объект и немного поправить Func (или написать свой).

Comment: @KoVadim прочитал ваш комментарий и вспомнил, что скриптовый движок позволяет биндить глобальные функции как методы класса, где первый аргумент - указатель на объект. Вот и выход! Но это не ответ на первоначальный вопрос.

Comment: @KoVadim А в чем заключается отличие метода, от функции-члена?

Comment: в том, что первого в плюсах нет, а второе есть.

Answer (score 2):

**Моё решение не подходит для общего случая.**

Получается, при моих ограничениях я могу только сделать `each` свободной функцией.

```
namespace SimpleXmlExtend
{

SimpleXmlNode& each(SimpleXmlNode* pthis, Sqrat::Function callback) {
    pthis->each([&callback](int i, SimpleXmlNode& child) {
        Sqrat::SharedPtr<bool> res = callback.Evaluate<bool>(i, child);

        if (!!res && *res) {
            return true;
        }
        i++;
        return false;
    });

    return *pthis;
}

}
```

Благо скриптовый движок позволяет биндить глобальные функции как функции класса, где первый аргумент - указатель на объект:

```
vm.GetRootTable().Bind("SimpleXmlNode", Class<SimpleXmlNode>(vm.GetVM(), "SimpleXmlNode").
     Func("Attribute", &SimpleXmlNode::Attribute).
     GlobalFunc("each", SimpleXmlExtend::each)
```

Пришлось в класс добавить функцию:

```
SimpleXmlNode& SimpleXmlNode::each(std::function<bool(int, SimpleXmlNode&)> callback) {
    int i = 0;
    TiXmlNode * child = 0;
    while ((child = impl_->m_el->IterateChildren(child)) != 0) {
        TiXmlElement* el = child->ToElement();
        SimpleXmlNode node(el);
        bool res = callback(i, node);
        if (res ) {
            break;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return *this;
}
```

Теперь я могу использовать похожий вызов функции `each` как в C++ коде, так и в скриптах.

Answer (score 1):

*Из комментария пользователя [@KoVadim](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/2739/kovadim):*

В C++ нет методов. Поэтому вопрос несколько некорректен. В C++ есть функции классов.

Можно зайти с другой стороны. Функции классов отличаются от обычных функций тем, что у них есть неявный первый аргумент, который указывает на вызвавший её объект. То есть можно создать свою функцию, которая первым аргументом получает указатель на объект, и немного поправить `Func` (или написать свой).